# Sign Flutter Application - Key Tool

Tags: android, flutter, keytool

Good time.
I have encountered a problem in signing my application in **CMD and Key Tool**.
After entering information such as name and password, after confirming the information and **typing the word "yes"**, I get an error that I will post a photo of.

[image: Error image in CMD]

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screen shot. It is just text, copy and paste it into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Seems like you tried to apply a tutorial but forgot to replace `USER_NAME` with your Windows user account name (see `echo %username%`).

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert, the problem was exactly what you said. The problem was solved by adding the Windows name.